# how to upload csv file in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

this   code is working perfect but when i add two row its not working

please help me to fix this issue
thanks

not working

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale2 (username, date, item, quantity, amount) VALUES
```

this is working

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale2 (username, date, item) VALUES
```

and this is complete code

```
<?php  

            //connect to the database 
            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
            mysql_select_db("member",$connect); //select the table 
            // 

            if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

                //get the csv file 
                $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
                $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

                //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
                do { 
                    if ($data[0]) { 
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale2 (username, date, item) VALUES 
                            ( 
                                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                                '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                                '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
            \

                            ) 
                        "); 
                    } 
                }  while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
                // 

                //redirect 
                header('Location: csv.php?success=1'); die; 

            } 

            ?> 

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
            <head> 
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
            <title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
            </head> 

            <body> 

            <?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
              Choose your file: <br /> 
              <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
            </form> 

            </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you mean not working?

Comment: no error show in page

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); at top of file

Comment: Is it getting redirected to the location you mentioned?

Comment: Consider to post sample data from your file and exact table schema

Comment: i think here is a problem there is three data                                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                                '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                                '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
            \

                            ) 
                        "); 
                    } 
                }  while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));

Comment: Do you add data for quantity and amount into the SQL? Do the columns exist in the database? If so, do they accept NULL?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sale2` (`username`, `date`, `item`, `quantity`, `amount`) VALUES 
                        (
                            '".trim($data[0], '"')."',
                            '".trim($data[1], '"')."', 
                            '".trim($data[2], '"')."',
                            '".trim($data[3], '"')."'
                        )
                    ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the error where your script is not working.
Also use exception handling try-catch action and get message through $e->getMessage();

```
try {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale2 (username, date, item) VALUES 
                        ( 
                            '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                            '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                            '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
        \

                        ) 
                    "); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: dear i replace ur code no error found and it  is showing this text but it is not upload  Your file has been imported.

Answer (score 0):

First Create the database below is code.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contacts`;
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contact_first` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `contact_last` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Second step created the csv file please have a look.

contacts.csv

```
Jim,Smith,jim@tester.com
Joe,Tester,joe@tester.com
```

Last step connect the database and run the import csv file below is the code.

```
 <?php  
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connect);


if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

    header('Location: index.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } ?> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert CSV file in collection first. After that you can add loop and call insert queries to insert data.

Here you will get code to convert CSV file into collection array.
[best-way-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-in-php](http://ask.btitinfosystems.com/18/best-way-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-in-php)